# Python: Input verification for checking if a number is in a list

Tags: python

This just loops infinitely. Even if I enter something like 10. I'm still a Python noob, sorry for the dumb question.

```
number_list = [10, 20, 30, 40]    
number = input("Enter a number: ")
while number not in number_list:
    number = input("Not a valid number, try again: ")
print(number)
```

Comment: input returns a string you need to convert it to an int.

Comment: ^^ read this answer again, it contains the secret answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input` returns a `str`, and you're comparing it to a list of `int`s.  Change it to:

```
number_list = [10, 20, 30, 40]    
number = int(input("Enter a number: "))
while number not in number_list:
    number = int(input("Not a valid number, try again: "))
print(number)
```

Comment: you forgot `number = int(input("Not a valid number, try again: "))`